# Shortest conversion from vector to vector of pointer

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any shortcut to convert from `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<T*>` or `std::vector<T&>`?

Essentially I want to replace:

```
std::vector<T> source;
std::vector<T*> target;
for(auto it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); it++)
{
  target.push_back(&(*it));
}
```

with a single line.

To provide some context: I have one set of functions which do their computation on a `std::vector<Polygon>` and some which require `std::vector<Polygon*>`. So I need to convert back and forth a couple of times, because the interface of these functions is not supposed to change.

Comment: Keep in mind you should do `target.reserve(source.size())` to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.

Comment: Is this safe? `target` will contain pointers to the objects stored in `source`. If `source` changes (i.e. an element is added), then the whole of `source` could be moved. It will be alright if you make sure that you regenerate `target` every time `source` changes.

Comment: @DanS: I got these functions which require `std::vector<T*>`, since nobody changes `source` while I call these, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although what you describe sounds strange (without context), using [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) you could do the actual copying/transformation in one line of code :

```
transform(source.begin(), source.end(), target.begin(), getPointer);
```

given that `target` has sufficient room for all data (can be achieved with [`std::vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) eg.), and given this unary operator :

```
template<typename T> T* getPointer(T& t) { return &t; }
```

Comment: If `target` is empty to begin with then using `back_inserter(target)` in place of `target.begin()` avoids the need to `resize`. But a `reserve` is still slightly worthwhile to avoid the vector re-allocating itself more than necessary.

Comment: But the 1 million dollar question is, where do those pointers point to after you dispose of the first vector (which will destruct all objects inside it)? -- still +1 for a very creative solution.

Comment: @Damon: It is the responsibility of the person who creates the target array to make sure the pointers remain valid.

Answer (score 7):

If you have got c++0x the following code does the trick (c++0x needed for lambdas):

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T*> convertFrom(std::vector<T>& source)
{
    std::vector<T*> target(source.size());
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), target.begin(), [](T& t) { return &t; });
    return target;
}
```

One side note: Make sure the source vector is not cleaned up before the last usage of the target vector as it is the owner of the actual objects. The target vector only contains the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea to my previous answer, is to use [boost iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html).

Since it's sufficiently different, I thought I'd post it as a new response :

First using the [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) :

```
template<typename T> T* getPointer(T& t) { return &t; }
boost::transform_iterator<T* (*)(T&), std::vector<T>::iterator> begin(source.begin(), getPointer), end(source.end(), getPointer);
std::vector<T*> target(begin, end);
```

Or to construct the `source` vector from the `target` vector (if that direction also works for you), you can use the [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html) :

```
boost::indirect_iterator<std::vector<T*>::iterator> begin(target.begin()), end(target.end());
std::vector<T> source(begin, end);
```

It might not be as pretty, but it's effective.